# Mapping Driver not applying changes

Tags: node-editor, displacement, procedural

I am following CGMatters Tutorial on procedural crystals but the added drivers to the mapping node are not making any changes when scaling the object in question. I'll add in an image, if anyone has an idea as to why this is happening I'd highly appreciate it.

Thanks and stay healthy everyone!

[enter link description here](https://www.directupload.net/file/d/6081/zyqnfd7r_jpg.htm)

Comment: Replace `1` by `var`in the expression

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still no improvement though